# How to get historical Bid and Ask price with python-binance

Tags: python, binance

I am using

```py
client.get_historical_klines('BTCUSDT', '15m', '1 Dec, 2019', '25 Apr, 2021', limit=500 )
```

to get historical price (mid point). But is there a way to get historical bid and ask price, rather than mid price, with python-binance api?

Answer (score 2):

According to the [Binance API documentation](https://binance-docs.github.io/apidocs/spot/en/#market-data-endpoints), there is no option to get historical data on the order book. Therefore there should be no option in `python-binance` either.

In the documentation, I see the following (nearest) endpoints:

- [Order Book](https://binance-docs.github.io/apidocs/spot/en/#order-book): Current order book for a selected symbol.
- [Old Trade Lookup](https://binance-docs.github.io/apidocs/spot/en/#old-trade-lookup): If you want to collect all historical trades (but without the bid/ask prices).
- [Symbol Order Book Ticker](https://binance-docs.github.io/apidocs/spot/en/#symbol-order-book-ticker): Best (current) price/qty on the order book for a symbol or symbols.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this?

Setting up the client:

```
client = Client(api_key=BINANCE_KEY, api_secret=BINANCE_SECRET)
symbol = 'ADAUSDT'
```

Pulling order book for the symbol and limiting the number of orders to 5:

```
order_book = client.get_order_book(symbol = symbol, limit=5)
```

Have a look:

```
print(order_book)
```

Output:

> {'lastUpdateId': 7361684802, 'bids': [['0.27820000',
> '14759.40000000'], ['0.27810000', '16864.50000000'], ['0.27800000',
> '28302.80000000'], ['0.27790000', '57196.20000000'], ['0.27780000',
> '90902.60000000']],   'asks': [['0.27830000', '11755.00000000'],
> ['0.27840000', '53573.90000000'], ['0.27850000', '34885.90000000'],
> ['0.27860000', '35419.20000000'], ['0.27870000', '26670.10000000']]}

Accessing the "order_book":

```
order_book['bids']
```

Output:

> ```
> [['0.27820000', '14759.40000000'],
>  ['0.27810000', '16864.50000000'],
>  ['0.27800000', '28302.80000000'],
>  ['0.27790000', '57196.20000000'],
>  ['0.27780000', '90902.60000000']]
> ```